# Бекап баз данных

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql

Всем добрый день. Возможно задам глупый вопрос но сам разобраться не могу. На сервере есть множество баз данных и необходимо сделать бекап. Но через phpmyadmin получается либо сразу все базы данных в один файл забекапить либо каждую по отдельности. Как сделать так что бы бекап всех баз данных сохранялся не в один файл а каждая база в свой sql файл.

Comment: @alexsis20102 А чем Вас консоль [не устраивает](http://habrahabr.ru/post/105954/). В Вашем случае, необходим [последовательный вызов команд](http://pingvinus.ru/note/run-multiple-commands)

Comment: Есть конкретный пример?? Нужно что бы запускался бекап каждая база данных сохранялась в отдельный файл с именем базы данных и расширением sql после чего возможно собиралось в архив и выдавалось на скачку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно, [shell](http://pastebin.com/zTrJLZwP). Поправьте в нём имена БД.

```
bash /home/romeo/dumps.sh -u username -p pass
```

Для домашних сборок я использую [phing](http://www.phing.info/) ([пример билда](http://pastebin.com/qmPVv7P4)), а так [ansible](http://www.ansible.com/home)